# Kendo UI sortable integration with ListView and Grid cause delete to fire multiple times after reordering the ListView items

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, grid, jquery-ui-sortable, crud

Hope somebody can set me in the right direction on this. I have a kendo ui ListView and Grid and a kendo sortable widget that's tied with the listview. The Grid also has a delete column. I am using those to upload and manage images. Now, when I reorder the listview items and grid items are being reordered as well as both the ListView and the Grid are tied to the same datasource.

However, upon reordering, if I press the delete button for a grid item, then the MVC action that takes care of the delete operation gets fired multiple times  actually, as many times as the number or reordering drag-and-drop operations I have done.

Here are some code snippets:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var pictureSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: "json",
                autoSync: false,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ProductPictureList", "Product", new { productId = Model.Id }))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ProductPictureUpdate", "Product"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ProductPictureDelete", "Product"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    errors: "Errors",
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            PictureUrl: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            DisplayOrder: { editable: true, type: "number" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                requestEnd: function(e) {
                    if (e.type == "update") {
                        debugger;
                        this.read();
                    }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                    // Cancel the changes
                    this.cancelChanges();
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            });

            $("#productpictures-grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: pictureSource,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    numeric: false,
                    previousNext: false,
                    info: false
                },
                editable: {
                    confirmation: false,
                    mode: "inline"
                },
                scrollable: false,
                columns: [{
                    field: "PictureUrl",
                    title: "@T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Pictures.Fields.Picture")",
                    template: '<a href="#=PictureUrl#" target="_blank"><img alt="#=PictureId#" src="#=PictureUrl#" width="150" /><a/>',
                    width: 200
                }, {
                    field: "DisplayOrder",
                    title: "@T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Pictures.Fields.DisplayOrder")",
                    //integer format
                    format: "{0:0}",
                    width: 150
                }, {
                    command: [{
                        name: "edit",
                        text: "@T("Admin.Common.Edit")"
                    }, {
                        name: "destroy",
                        text: "@T("Admin.Common.Delete")"
                    }],
                    width: 200
                }]
            });



            $("#listView").kendoListView({
                dataSource: pictureSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
            });


            $("#listView").kendoSortable({
                filter: ">div.product",
                cursor: "move",
                placeholder: function(element) {
                    return element.clone().css("opacity", 0.1);
                },
                hint: function(element) {
                    return element.clone().removeClass("k-state-selected");
                },
                start: function(e) {

                },
                change: function(e) {
                    var
                        oldIndex = e.oldIndex,
                        newIndex = e.newIndex,
                        data = pictureSource.data(),
                        dataItem = pictureSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));


                    pictureSource.remove(dataItem);
                    pictureSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SwapPictures", "Product"))",
                        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            picturesString: kendo.stringify(pictureSource.data()),
                            productId: @Model.Id
                            }),
                        success: function(response) {
                            pictureSource.read();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.